# SQL Query to select several instances of one column based on conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, join, inner-join

I'm joining 3 tables:

```
SELECT TABLE1.FIELD1
FROM TABLE1
JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE1.ID = TABLE2.FK
JOIN TABLE3 ON TABLE2.ID = TABLE3.FK
```

I'd like to select several column of `TABLE2.FIELD1` based on some conditions, e.g, `TABLE2.FIELD1 WHERE TABLE2.CONDITIONI`, `TABLE2.FIELD1 WHERE TABLE3.ANOTHERCONDITION`.

So the end result is something like this:

```
TABLE1.FIELD1 | TABLE2.FIELD1 BASE ON CON1 | TABLE2.FIELD1 BASED ON CON2
```

I'm not sure if I'm clear enough, please ask for further clarification if it's needed.

A sample report:

```
Id |   Product | Income Quantity | Outcome Quantity
```

In this sample, Quantity, in just one field in the second table that has been joint on the product table. It's been rendered twice in the output based on different conditions, e.g, income is where `header.flow == 1` and outgoing is where `header.flow == -1`.

Comment: Sample data and expected output will help us to understand better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

```
SELECT ID,
       CASE WHEN flow = 1 THEN Quantity ELSE NULL END as 'Income',
       CASE WHEN flow = -1 THEN Quantity ELSE NULL END as 'Outcome'
FROM Sample
```

Just add you joins as required at the end and change your conditions in the CASE statement

---

As per your comment

> I have to use group by for flow and SUM(quantity). and I'll have two columns for each product.

You could try this instead:

```
SELECT s1.ID,
    (SELECT SUM(Quantity) FROM SAMPLE s2 WHERE s2.ID = S1.ID AND S2.FLOW = 1) as 'Income',
    (SELECT SUM(Quantity) FROM SAMPLE s2 WHERE s2.ID = S1.ID AND S2.FLOW = -1) as 'Outgoing'
FROM Sample S1
GROUP BY ID
```

Which could also be achieved by

```
SELECT DISTINCT s1.ID,
    (SELECT SUM(Quantity) FROM SAMPLE s2 WHERE s2.ID = S1.ID AND S2.FLOW = 1) as 'Income',
    (SELECT SUM(Quantity) FROM SAMPLE s2 WHERE s2.ID = S1.ID AND S2.FLOW = -1) as 'Outgoing'
FROM Sample S1
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but seems like you should use `CASE` statement

```
select 
case when <<cod1>> then
table1.field
when <<cod2>> then 
table2.field
end 
from your_table1
inner join your_table2 on <<condition>>
```